# Does Google Activity Recognition work on older versions of Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I want to develop a test application that implements Activity Recognition on Android 4.1, but I saw on the documentation that only 4.2.2 is supported. I saw also that apps like AutomateIt (that includes Recognition functionality) work on my Jellybean 4.1. How could achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

[Google's own sample code](http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html) works back to API Level 8, according to its manifest. Everything in Google Play Services should work back to a similar API level, as [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/index.html) states:

> When using these services, you can distribute your app on Google Play to all devices running Android 2.2 or higher, and some services support even more devices.

Comment: As the developer of `AutomateIt` I can say that it does work on API Level 8 and above. Just make sure to check for Google Play Services availability using `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` method (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context))

Answer (score 0):

Briefly: update **GooglePlayServices** to the latest version.

**ActivityRecognitionApi** itself works starting from API 8.

Thus your problem could be that you have an old version of GooglePlayServices.

I had this issue on old device with Android 2.3.

As I understood that the problem was in the installed version of Google Play services (6.3); the issue has gone after updating GPservices app to 7.8.99. 
The was no straight way to update by pressing “update” button, but I had to delete manually Google Pay services app and then Android automatically installed the latest at that moment version 7.8.99.

My app started to show current activity quite accurate.

The strange thing is that Activity Recognition was introduced in much earlier version of Google Play services (earlier than 4.0).

In conclusion, I would say that the prerequisites for correct work of google activity APIs are:

- Google Play services client library (latest version)
- Android version 2.2 (API level 8) or newer.