# Android Location Update Clarification

Tags: android, gps, location

Am working with the location update application which will update the user location periodically to the server.

I have used the fused location provider to get the location update. I have referred the following link [**Android Location Update**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html).

Regarding the location update I have following ***clarifications***,

> 1) I requested Location using Pending Intent. I had given the Time
>   interval as 5 min in the location request. I am getting the location
>   information successfully at every 5 min. But my question is "How effectively
>   Android uses the GPS to get the location - GPS need not to be on for
>   the whole 5 min". Around 4 min 50 seconds it starts using the GPS to
>   get the user location. I just want to know how the fused location provider effectively using the GPS.
>
> 2) And also I want to know the time taken to fetch the user location
>   by using available providers. How much time approximately taken by the
>   android api to get the user location by using fusion location
>   provider.
>
> 3) The Fused Location Provider uses GPS only at the nearest time of given interval to get
>   the user location. The remaining time the GPS is not usable. Is there
>   is better solution to switch off the GPs or effective way to use the
>   GPS to save the mobile battery power.
>
> 4) Am giving the time interval as 1 min. Some time am not getting the
>   location update every one minute. For Example, First minute successfully
>   I am getting the user location. Then not getting the user location at 2nd Minute. Then 3rd minute
>   getting fine and so. I have GPS ON and with mobile network available and WiFi
>   connected.
>
> 5) And what is the maximum time interval we can give. Am not finding
>   any maximum time limit in the document. We can give the minimum time interval as zero. But it is not recommended.
>
> 6) And also I want to know the minimum OS support while using this feature. I have referred below link [Does Google Activity Recognition work on older versions of Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428318/does-google-activity-recognition-work-on-older-versions-of-android) Which says Everything in Google Play Services should work back to API level 8(Android 2.3).

Please help me on this. I hope this could help other developer also who are working on Android Location Updates.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
I have used the fused location provider API's in our project and it's was really helpful to improve battery usage.Earlier We were using Android's Location framework APi's .

Please read below article which I have prepared ,you can refer the information to implement it in your project.

In simple words, it’s the best way to get location data in Android platform as of now.
GooglePlay Services provide many location APi’s to get the location data(e.g. User’s current location or you can say device’s last known location).

The Fused Location Provider is one of the location APIs in Google Play services.
Prerequisite is that:
1-        Google Play services sdk is used as library project(and also Google PlayService is properly installed in your device)
Download and install the Google Play services component from  the SDK Manager and add the library to your project.
Import GooglePlayServices lib from android google-play-services_lib in  your development  project as  Library project.
2-      You should have an actual device as this APi won’t work in Emulator.

The Fused Location Provider intelligently manages the underlying location technology (GPS/Wi-Fi/Network provider’s connection) and gives us the best location according to our needs.

Why to use
============= 
We could choose one of the location providers (network or GPS) and request location updates or set up proximity alert. But there were two main issues with this approach:
1. In case we need to define precise location, we had to switch between network and GPS location providers (as GPS doesn’t work indoors).
2. Proximity alerts were used to notify a user about proximity to a location, and this took its toll on the battery life.

Benefits
 ==========
1. Simple APIs: Lets us specify high-level needs like “high accuracy” or “low power”, instead of having to worry about location providers.
2. Battery efficient: Minimizes out app’s use of power. Based on all incoming location requests and available sensors, fused location provider chooses the most efficient way to meet those needs.

Steps to use this Api:
 =====================
1-      Declare the location related permission in the manifest file.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION"/>
  Or
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


2. Implement related interfaces and callbacks.

  Before we request location updates, we must first implement the interfaces that Location Services uses to communicate connection status to our app:
2.1 com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks: Specifies methods that Location Services calls when a location client is connected or disconnected.
2.2
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
3 Connect to Google Play Services

Connecting LocationClient to Google api.To do this , create a LocationClient object (it’s actually instance of GoogleApiClient object)  as below:

mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                                 .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                                                 .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

and then call connect() :
mLocationClient.connect();

4- Create an instance of FusedLocationProviderApi by using LocationServices class as below:

private FusedLocationProviderApi fusedLocationProviderApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;

5- Retrieve the current location

 Inside onConnected(Bundle bundle){

Location currentLocation = fusedLocationProviderApi                                  .getLastLocation(mLocationClient);
                 if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
                                 Log.d(TAG, "last location =" +           mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()
                                                                 + " - " + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
 }              
 }

6-  Receive periodic location updates

 Create and setup LocationRequest object:
mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

private void setLocationParameter() {
                 // Set the update interval
                 mLocationRequest.setInterval(Constants.SECONDS_TO_UP);
                 // Use high accuracy
                 mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                 // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
                 mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(Constants.SECONDS_TO_UP);
                 // Set the distance to 10 meters.
                 mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(Constants.METERS_TO_UP);
   }


6- Request for periodic Location updates: To get periodic location updates from Location Services, we send a request using a location client.

LocationListener listener =  new LocationListener() {
           @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {    
                                 Utils.locationUpdates = Utils.locationUpdates + 1;
                                 if (Utils.locationUpdates == 1) {
                                                 mLocationRequest
                                                                                 .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                                                 mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, listener);

                                                    }
                 }
          }
       };
```

Comment: We analyzed and finally thought of using Android SDK provided location manager to get the location information. Even if u use the Google play services to get the location information the drawbacks are you can not support most of end user this is because most of the device is not having google play store installed. And another one is the accuracy is not that much good when compared with location api.

Comment: Hi Vignesh, Yes ,the device should have Google PlayStore installed on the device. But I am not sure if using Fused Location Provider is less accurate than using Location manager API's.How would you confirm this point?

Comment: Using fusedLocation Provider api,you can configure for  high accuracy or low power. It gives more  accurate results than Location Manager api.

Comment: No I have plotted both the results. The Location Manager points are getting plotted in the road path. But Fused Api points are slightly away from road path.

Comment: If you are using location manager then you have to define your own logic which will impact the battery. We have defined an logic such away that the logic consumes only less power.