# android detect ActivityRecognition in background

Tags: android, service

I`d like to detect user user's activity in background when app is closed. There is an example of using ActivityRecognition from Google APIs for Android.
In the example the recognition is initiated by an Activity, and I made my service realization.
It works fine on most devices but not on devices with api 4.2.x.

```
public class RecognitionService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    ResultCallback<Status> {
private static final String TAG = RecognitionService.class.getSimpleName();
public final static int DETECTION_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 60_000;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

public RecognitionService() {
    super();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    initLocationClient();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private void initLocationClient() {
    if (googleApiClient == null) {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
                .build();
    }

    if (!googleApiClient.isConnected() || !googleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");
    if (googleApiClient != null && googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(
                googleApiClient,
                DETECTION_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS,
                getActivityDetectionPendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
}

private PendingIntent getActivityDetectionPendingIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetectedActivitiesIntentService.class);

    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when calling
    // requestActivityUpdates() and removeActivityUpdates().
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

@Override
public void onResult(Status status) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onResult = " + status.getStatusMessage());
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
    ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.removeActivityUpdates(
            googleApiClient,
            getActivityDetectionPendingIntent()
    ).setResultCallback(this);
}
}
```

Methods onConnected, onConnectionSuspended, onConnectionFailed are not called.

Do you have any ideas about this case?

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that the device has the the correct version of GooglePlayServices installed using [isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)):

```
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvail = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int errorCode = apiAvail.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (errorCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        // okay
    } else {
        // not available; start processing to resolve
    }
```

Although unavailability of Play Services should be reported after a connection request to `onConnectionFailed()`, using `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` offers another means to check availability.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428318/does-google-activity-recognition-work-on-older-versions-of-android) addresses version support for ActivityRecognition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, GooglePlayServices are correct

Comment: So `googleApiClient.connect()` is called and there are no callbacks at all?  Anything in the logcat?